# Oracle SQL: Xmlagg with several Xmlelement / columns in Select

Tags: xml, oracle, select, trim, string-concatenation

I have the following as part of a larger Select query which works fine so far and helps me to get just one row for each record in column1.

However, this returns a separate XML element for column2, column3 and column4 whereas I need them all in one column.

**Can someone tell me how I can combine the XML elements for these three columns in one ?**
When researching this I came across `XMLFOREST` but this doesn't seem to be a widely used function and I am not sure how to apply it here.

**My query (relevant part):**

```
SELECT
    a.column1 AS Column1
    , RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(e, b.column2) ORDER BY b.column2).EXTRACT('//text()'), ',') AS Column2
    , RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(e, b.column3) ORDER BY b.column3).EXTRACT('//text()'), ',') AS Column3
    , RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(e, b.column4) ORDER BY b.column4).EXTRACT('//text()'), ',') AS Column4
    , c.column5 AS Column5
    /* ... */
FROM
    /* ... */
```

**Current output:**
[image: Current output]

**Required output:**
[image: Required output]

Many thanks in advance for any help,
Mike

Comment: You'll get better answers faster if you include the output you get and the output you want.

Comment: @jeff6times7: Thanks. I have added this now to the post. Basically I am trying to combine the data from columns 2, 3 and 4 for each unique record in column 1. The difference to the current output is that I want this combined in one column instead of having three separate columns for it.

Comment: It could be nice if you had attached sample input XML for desired output.

Comment: @krokodilko: Thanks. I don't need XML at all, I just use this as a workaround as I am exceeding the character limit for Listagg. I just need to combine columns 2 to 4 for each unique record in column 1, like in the pictures above. I need only one row for each unique record in column 1.

Comment: You say that something like this will not work? `SELECT
    a.column1 AS Column1
, RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(e, b.column2||b.column3||b.column4) ORDER BY b.column2||b.column3||b.column4).EXTRACT('//text()'), ',') AS Column2
    , c.column5 AS Column3
    /* ... */
FROM
    /* ... */` - please check this one. If it doesn't work, paste here the raw structure of the b.column2, b.column3 and b.column4 columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    a.column1 AS Column1
    , RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(e, b.column2||','||b.column3||','||b.column4) ORDER BY b.column2).EXTRACT('//text()'), ',') AS Column2
    , c.column5 AS Column5
    /* ... */
FROM
    /* ... */
```

Comment: Pls explain in your own words, how this will solve the problem in question to add value to your answer instead of code only answer.